# Are you on Facebook

Tags: social-network, social, websites, facebook

Hi guys and girls,
This is not really a question... Who is using Facebook here?

My profile is http://www.facebook.com/cvrgoje

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about information that can be shared in profiles.

Answer (score 2):

I quit last year after I realized that Facebook took too much of my time. Another reason was that communication between friends became kinda weird, because you tend to just drop a message rather than calling someone.

Answer (score 1):

Still have it to keep in contact with people who don't answer their phones! But other than keeping in touch with old friends that have changed their numbers or don't answer I don't really like it. As mny said it takes up to much time and doesn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

Am on it, don't really use... Maybe if they added a Don't Like button I might use it more ;)
As William Gibson said "Facebook is like the mall, Twitter is like the street" or someone else said "Facebook makes you hate your friends and Twitter makes you like people you don't know"

Comment: I hate malls, and therefore have never, and still don't, have a Facebook presence of any kind. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use FB as a way to contact friends who I don't see often enough (live away from my area), and Twitter is the place to meet lovely people like Sound Designers :)

Answer (score 0):

I've moved around quite a bit in my life so I find FB invaluable for keeping up with friends.  I also have a page for the studio and while I can't say I've received a job via the FB page I do receive a lot of feedback regarding the postings about what the studio is up to.  John.